# Como obter um elemento que está dentro de dois ou mais elementos?

Tags: javascript, query

Eu estou utilizando o método `querySelector` para obter um elemento que está dentro de três elementos de `<div>` como no código abaixo:

```html
<div class="main">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Elemento Alvo</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O problema é que se eu utilizar o seletor `".main > span"` o método não retorna nada, a não ser que eu coloque no seletor os outros elementos dessa forma:

```
document.querySelector(".main > div > div > span");
```

Eu gostaria de saber como posso obter o elemento alvo sem precisa deixar explícito os seus parentes. Eu sei que é possível fazer isso com Jquery, mas quero saber como faço em JS puro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seletor `>` que você está usando é para descendentes imediatos, ou seja, `.main > div` significa um div filho de um elemento com a classe main. Para pegar descendentes em qualquer nível, use simplesmente um espaço:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".main span"); // Todos os spans dentro de .main
```